# About a past question

Tags: group-theory, reference-request

In [What is the center of a semidirect product?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/243327/what-is-the-center-of-a-semidirect-product-operatornamezg-1-rtimes-varph), Alexander Gruber answered a question of user39794. Is there cited reference for this? I want to cite this result. Is it given in some book or paper? Kindly tell me the reference for that.

Comment: You should ask this as a comment on the original question....

Comment: This question should be asked as a comment on the question the OP references.

Comment: @ Simon Hayward, @ Nicholas R. Peterson To comment on other question I need 50 reputation score which I do not have. Therefore I asked this as new question.

Answer (score 3):

I dunno if it's anywhere in the literature, I just derived it.  If you want, you can cite the MSE post using this BibTeX code

```
@MISC {243412,
TITLE = {What is the center of a semidirect product, $\operatorname{Z}(G_1 \rtimes_\varphi G_2)$?},
AUTHOR = {Alexander Gruber (http://math.stackexchange.com/users/12952/alexander-gruber)},
HOWPUBLISHED = {Mathematics Stack Exchange},
NOTE = {URL:http://math.stackexchange.com/q/243412 (version: 2013-06-02)},
EPRINT = {http://math.stackexchange.com/q/243412},
URL = {http://math.stackexchange.com/q/243412}
}
```

which I got from using MSE's built in citation thingamajig, as described by [WillieWong here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/8218/12952).

If you don't want to do that, I doubt it'd be in any papers, but you could look around in semidirect product sections in Dummit and Foote or Artin and see if it occurs as a problem somewhere.

Comment: Why answering a question which should have been asked as a comment on the original question?

Comment: Knew the answer

Comment: Not sufficient.

Comment: That ain't up to you, @Did.

Comment: Sorry but this won't do: to say that one answers *any* question just because one "knew the answer" is to deliberately flout the fact that MSE has a well defined, restricted, scope, which, by pure logic, implies that some questions are out of this scope. (Incidentally, the tone of your two comments is most peculiar.)

Comment: @Did The question was a reference request, which is within the scope of MSE.  it might have worked better as a comment, or maybe as a meta math SE question, but it does not *have* to be one of those, and I felt it was simplest to answer here.  incidentally, I don't know why you think it necessary to fill this answer with meta criticisms. My tone was meant to convey that I do not find this conversation productive. if you'd like me to be more direct, they mean, "you have cast your close vote, which is as much say as you get in this matter."

Comment: also, for the record, i'd vote to reopen if mine wasn't unilateral.

Comment: To adopt a condescending tone (which you acknowledge) instead of addressing at the onset the specific and restricted point I raised is a choice you can make. Allow me to disagree.