# Groups of order $2pqr$

Tags: group-theory

What are the groups of order $2pqr$ up to isomorphism, where $p$, $q$, $r$ are distinct primes greater than $2$? How would you identify them?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Why not try some special cases first? If you tell me the groups of order $2.3.7.43$ that you can find then I'll check if you've found them all.

Answer (score 1):

Finite group of squarefree order is solvable (it follows from the fact that Sylow subgroups are cyclic). As it's solvable, it has all Hall subgroups, in particular, maximal subgroup of odd order. It has index 2, therefore normal. (First part of this paragraph is probably an overkill reasoning, but the first one that popped in my head.)

So you have split extension 
$$G = C_2 \ltimes H$$

Denote odd primes dividing $|H|$ as $p < q < r$.

First, assume $(q, r-1) = 1$, so $p'$-Hall subgroup of $H$ is abelian.

1. $(p, q-1) = (p, r-1) = 1$, then $H = C_{pqr}$ (it's obvious)
2. $p | q-1$ or $p|r-1$, but not both. Then $H = C_{pqr}$, $H = (C_p \ltimes C_q) \times C_r$ or $H = (C_p \ltimes C_r) \times C_q$  (also pretty easy to see)
3. $p$ divides both $q-1$ an $r-1$. Then there are $p+2$ different semidirect products $C_p \ltimes C_{qr}$ incluing trivial one $C_{pqr}$. Proof I'm aware of is elementary, but long and tedious, so I wouldn't reproduce it here. I suspect that some nifty number-theoretic argument makes it easy, but old case by case analysis still does the job.

Also you want classification when $q|r-1$. It's too long for an answer here, but it's done already by Hölder in 1893 — you can look up if you're not afraid of ancient notation. (There should be more modern exposition, but I do not remember any.)

---

Then, finally, after possible $H$'s are identified, you want to somehow understand which involutions in $Aut(H)$ will give same semidirect products. There's no general recipe to do this, but we're lucky enough to be in simple enough situation.

In case $H = C_{pqr}$ see answer to this https://math.stackexchange.com/q/571248 question. If $H$ is cyclic times nonabelian, then similarly to previous case we can treat those direct factors disjointly (because there are no nonzero homomorphisms between them), and both cases are already classified above (we haven't used that $p, q, r$ are odd in section about $H$).

There's also hard one when $H$ is indecomposable; I guess you can find full classification in some article, but it almost guaranteed to be just tedious analysis of multiple cases.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can you please tell me the link to Holders publication? I tried to find it out but can't find it. I want to find all the publications by Holder (There is a publication on groups of order $pq^2$ and $pqrs$ but it seems none are available).